# XCode: Keep a multiplayer game running in background state

Tags: ios, xcode, background-process, multiplayer

I'm programming a location-based multiplayer game for iOS. This game is live-action, so it's very important that the user is connected and communicating to the backend servers for the duration of their gameplay.

I'm trying to figure out how to handle gameplay connectivity when the app goes into background, short of terminating (which would simply cause the user to leave their game). Since games can be very lengthy in terms of time, and since the user may want to do some other things with other apps on their phone while the game is still running, I need to be able to continue running the game while the app is in in the background state. This basically just means keeping connection with the backend database, doing writes and reads, and getting location data.

I know how to keep the user's game instance running in background via UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask, but this expires after some time. How can I keep the user's connection to the game running in background, indefinitely, until either the app becomes active again or terminates?

I'm using swift 3 if anyone cares.

Comment: we need more information about what kind of backend you have?
since its a multi player game, I guess you should be using engines like smartfox or other multiplayer engines... If you are already using an engine, it automatically take care of keeping the game in passive state by adjusting appropriate variable time limit....

Comment: I'm using Firebase. This isn't a graphics based game so I don't need an engine. All i need is the ability to keep interfacing with the backend while the app is in background.

Comment: Did you add FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true ? in didFinishLauchOptions.......?

Comment: No, persistence of data isn't my issue. My issue is, while in background mode, keeping connection to the real time database as it is being updated live by other users, until the app either terminates or becomes active again. In other words I want a background task that doesn't expire.

Comment: try this
https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/